# 3d Object as marker in augmented reality

Tags: android, ios, 3d, augmented-reality

I want to make an application of augmented reality, and my application would have to detect 3d object as marker or real object i googled and find some work who are doing same thing like use building as marker or any other place but it did through GPS system i don't want to do that kind of thing, i need to work marker detection which is already working for 2d in Vuforia sdk. I want to know that is this possible that i can use 3d object or real object as a marker in augmented reality, If yes then would you suggest me that which any sdk for which will help me to build this in iPhone and android like Vuforia.
Thanks in advance, have a great day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metaio is a fairly easy to use AR SDK available for both Android and iPhone that has 3D tracking capabilities:

https://dev.metaio.com/sdk/tracking-configuration/optical-tracking-technologies/markerless-3d/

The non-watermarked version that supports 3D tracking, however, is expensive. A free alternative (currently) is to use the Junaio browser that Metaio makes to provide a 3D tracking AR experience:

http://www.junaio.com/develop/quickstart/3d-tracking-and-junaio/

I have experience with both of them but I have not used the 3D tracking features yet so I am not sure if you could track an actual building, but from the demos things such as boxes and similar objects appear to be supported well.

Good luck!